# Android google analytics easytracker - track event call in onCreate method of launcher activity crashes

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using EasyTracker google analytics library and my app have multiple activities.
I want to track as event device model and system version info each time on app launch.

This code in onCreate method of my launcher activity

```
EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent("Others", "App launch", "The os version", 0);
```

crashes with

```
06-15 21:24:30.898: WARN/dalvikvm(1203): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-15 21:24:30.898: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1203): FATAL EXCEPTION: TrackerThread
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker.createEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker.trackEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.GoogleAnalyticsTrackerDelegateImpl.trackEvent(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.EasyTracker$11.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.apps.analytics.easytracking.EasyTracker$TrackerThread.run(Unknown Source)
06-15 21:24:30.918: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Force finishing activity com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.activity.HomeActivity
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful to see more of the activity. Is your activity extending the TrackedActivity class or is it only extending the Activity class?

Comment: Additionally, minus that line is the tracking working properly. I see it requires a configuration file in the XML. Did you set that up?

Comment: Yes, my activity is extending TrackedActivity. Minus that line tracking also works properly, e.g. pageviews shown in google analytics web interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get a NullPointerException because the tracker is initialized in the onStart method of the base class TrackedActivity, which happens after onCreate. 
However, TrackedActivity automatically tracks the creation of the activity (trackPageView) so normally you do not need trackEvent here. You can successfully call trackEvent on any other method between onStart and onStop on the activity's lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Remember add the following code in activity.onCreate:

```
EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);
```

before using any tracker feature.